# Create lp token and add liquidity in BSCTestnet

Tags: solidity, binance-smart-chain

I tried to create lp token from token created in bsctestnet and BNB
I used this testnet router address `0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1` where there are two functions. Which of them should i use:
`addLiquidityETH` or `addLiquidity` .
When i used the first function i get contract error..reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addLiquidityETH` but you first need to approve the needed amount (or the max), e.i.

```
IERC20(uniswapV2Pair).approve(address(uniswapV2Router),type(uint).max);
uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityEth{value:ethAmount}(...);
```